# QPluginLoader can't find module

Tags: qt, gdal

I have created a plugin for my application. If I don't use the GDAL library in my code, my application can use this plugin (QPlugin loads it) and it works fine. But if I use classes from the GDAL library `QPluginLoader` can't load it and the `errorstring()` method returns `../serverplugin.dll Can't find module`.

There are two  exported symbols `qt_plugin_instance` and `qt_plugin_query_verification_data` in the plugin DLL (I found them with Dependency walker). `QPluginLoader` uses the `QLibrary` class internally to interface with the C symbols exported to the DLL. If I don't use GDAL I have only two exported symbols in all plugins at the beginning. When I use GDAL these two symbols are moved at the end of a big list of exported symbols. Maybe these two exported symbols should be at the beginning.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with QPluginLoader. In few words how I solved it: I create plugin library, let's say lib1.dll which use some stuff from lib2.dll. In my application I try to load lib1 via QPluginLoader.

```
QPluginLoader loader( adaptersDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName) );
AdapterInterface* adapterIface = qobject_cast<AdapterInterface*>(loader.instance());
```

In this case loader.instance() returns 0. Solution was to copy lib2.dll into application folder because an application use it for proper load plugin lib1.

Answer (score 0):

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
#define Plugin_iid "Plugin"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(PluginInterface,Plugin_iid)
QT_END_NAMESPACE 

Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "PluginInterface" FILE "Plugin.json")
Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
```

Comment: Check to see if you have missed or written some of the following code incorrectly

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: The question seems quite detailed with, for instance, reference to two exported symbols qt_plugin_instance and qt_plugin_query_verification_data, but your answer doesn't refer to them so it's hard to see a connection between the question and your answer without explanation.